# Can you configure other installation commands in yeoman, beyond the standards that it can run on your self generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

Can you configure other installation commands in yeoman, beyond the standards(bower, npm) that it can run on your self generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in full control of the generator you write, so there's nothing stopping you from executing any command you would like, including other installation tools.

If you take a look at the `install.js` file in `yeoman-generator` you'll see that `runInstall`  (which is run by `installDependencies`, `bowerInstall` and `npmInstall`) just combines some arguments that are then executed by `this.spawnCommand`:

```
var args = ['install'].concat(paths).concat(dargs(options));

this.spawnCommand(installer, args, cb)
  .on('error', cb)
  .on('exit', this.emit.bind(this, installer + 'Install:end', paths))
  .on('exit', function (err) {
    if (err === 127) {
      this.log.error('Could not find ' + installer + '. Please install with ' +
                          '`npm install -g ' + installer + '`.');
    }
    cb(err);
  }.bind(this));
```

([Source](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/c7c1916a9388b3eff20d86c183ba909b96b1197c/lib/actions/install.js#L30))

If you want to run a custom tool to install dependencies, you can just define a function like this in your own generator.